# Defining non-linear limiting lines to dataset in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have some set of *(x,y)* data. Plotting this in python simply gives[image]

I want to be able to fit some lines or contours to this data, defining the inner and outer radii, such that I can then randomly select a point within those limits.

However, I have no idea where to even start. Any ideas?

Comment: Code you currently have and library you are using please

Comment: If your data is circular or an ellipse you might use [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0ahUKEwigjI-sia7WAhXM5xoKHYj-Bm8QFghjMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stsci.edu%2F~RAB%2FBackup%2520Oct%252022%25202011%2Ff_3_CalculationForWFIRSTML%2FGaertner%2520%26%2520Schoenherr.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFrKPRtr_5KBSnlCB90ikYmsZqtLw) for the outer and maybe the 1/zz* trick (see comment on reply below) for the inner boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If that are concentric circles, I would calculate average x and y coordinates (that would be the center), and then compute distances between each point and the center. Maximal and minimal distance would be the radii of inner and outer circle. (You could also choose other percentile if you wish).

If that are not circles, but something more complex, you could approximate outer shape as poligon using [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), and innner using something like [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) (Or use marching squares for both). Than you could do [point inside poligon test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for points you choose.

Comment: Maybe, if (0,0) is inside one could fit a convex hull to the 1/zz* transformed data and transform back to get the inner limit.

Comment: @mikuszefski Interesting. What is 1/zz* transformed data? Because from my university I remember only that we could obtain Delauney triangulation of points in n-dimensional space from convex hull of the same points in n+1 dimensional space where last coordinate is euclidean norm of all the others coordinates squared. But I remember nothing about transformations to find contours.

Comment: I was just thinking to make the reflection at the unit circle, turning inside out. As it is 2D data I would put z= x+i y then (z z*)^(-1) is the according reflection. Weather or not this might work depends on the typical data of the OP.